# how to sort List<T> where T is my own class and i want to sort by class.someString

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

So I have a class

```
Class MyClass{
    string myString;

    MyClass(string newString){
    myString = newString;
    }
}
```

and I have a list of these

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
myList.Add(new MyClass(some string...);
```

can i use List.Sort to order the objects based on the value of a field of the class?
and if so how?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.OrderBy`:

```
myList = myList.OrderBy(x => x.myString).ToList();
```

Note, though, that this creates a new list based on the old list. In many cases that won't make a difference, but it's something to be aware of.

---

Alternatively, since you are limited to .NET 2.0, you can define a custom function for comparison

```
class MyClass
{
    string myString;

    ...

    public static int CompareByMyString(MyClass x, MyClass y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x.myString, y.myString);
    }
}
```

and provide it to [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
myList.Sort(MyClass.CompareByMyString);
```

Comment: forgot to mention im limited to .net 2.0 cause im working in mono for unity and that seems to be .net 3.5 earliest

Comment: @user1711383: I've added an alternative using List.Sort, which should work with .net 2.0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can Inherit from IComparable. An example of this is:

```
public class MyClass : IComparable
    {
        public int Day { get; set; }
        public int Hour { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is MyClass)
            {
                MyClass slot = (MyClass)obj;

                if (Day < slot.Day)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else if (Day > slot.Day)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Hour < slot.Hour)
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else if (Hour > slot.Hour)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Object is not MyClass");
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return Day.GetHashCode() ^ Hour.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is MyClass)
            {
                return this == (MyClass)obj;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Object is not MyClass");
            }
        }

        public static bool operator ==(MyClass a, MyClass b)
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) == 0;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(MyClass a, MyClass b)
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) != 0;
        }

        public static bool operator <(MyClass a, MyClass b)
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) < 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >(MyClass a, MyClass b)
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) > 0;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(MyClass a, MyClass b)
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) <= 0;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(MyClass a, MyClass b)
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b) >= 0;
        }
    }
```

And then you could do this:

```
List<MyClass> listOfStuff = new List<MyClass>();}
// Add some stuff to the list E.G. 
listOfStuff.add(new MyClass());
// Sort the list
listOfStuff.sort();
```